# I cant make my bot go online and it shows TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS] (vscode)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Bot = new Discord.Client({Intents:[Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]})

Bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("The bot is online") 

    let commands = Bot.application.commands;

    commands.create({
        name: "hello" ,
        description: "reply hello to the user",
        options: [
            {
                name: "person",
                description: "The user you want to say hello to",
                require: true,
                type: Discord.Constants.ApplicationCommandOptionTypes.USER

            }
        ]
    })
 })
    

    Bot.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
     if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;
     let name  = interaction.commandName
     let options = interaction.options;

     if(name == "hello") {
        interaction.reply({
            content: "Hello",
            ephemeral: false
        })
    }
    if(name == "sayhello"){
        let user = options.getUser('person');

        interaction.reply({
            content: 'Hello ${user.username}
        })
    }
})

bot.login("token")
```

Comment: It shows It shows TYPEERROR'[CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client. and        
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0):

Since `discord.js` v13, you need to provide [`Intents`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#gateway-intents) when declaring the client. They were introduced by Discord so that developers can choose what type of data the bot will need to receive. All you have to do is add intents when declaring the client. The code might look something like this:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
})
```

And also, as pointed by @Richie Bendall, you have capitalised the I when declaring the intents. You can learn more about intents in here => [Gateway Intents | Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents)

Answer (score 0):

The `intents` is option is lowercase, not capitalised. See [`ClientOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/ClientOptions).

Answer (score 0):

Well actually since the new discord.js update you need to provide the intents to the bot. This might help

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```